# Calling a class and function using variable

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I have been wondering if it is possible to call function like this

```
//
public function getDataSource($id,$source,Request $request){

    $form = 'Invoice';
    $fuToCall = $source;

    return \App\Core\Forms\.$form.\.$form.DataSource::$fuToCall();


}
```

The concatenation of my $form name doesn't work, why? Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really concatenating strings. The non-dynamic part of namespace in your example isn't a string.

You can do it like this:

```
$class = '\App\Core\Forms\\'.$form.'\\'.$form.'\DataSource';
return $class::$fuToCall();
```

Or with 1 line:

```
return ('\App\Core\Forms\\'.$form.'\\'.$form.'\DataSource')::$funcToCall();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
call_user_func('\App\Core\Forms\\' . $form . '\\' . $form . '\\DataSource', 'fuToCall');
```